# Android room database with two tables

Tags: android, android-room

I'm getting started with my first MVVM application. I need two tables here. One called tasks where I have the task, whether its completed or not and stuff like that. The other table is for saving notes which has think like title, sub-title and such.

So to implement this with room database, should I just create a single room database with two tables or do I create two separate databases, which would be better and why.

Comment: Create a single room database with two or more tables. You can choose to connect these tables or not using foreign key. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1705381/9110576

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a reason to use two databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705381/is-there-a-reason-to-use-two-databases)

Comment: yes it does. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typically simpler and more efficient to use a single database with multiple tables as opposed to multiple databases with tables distributed between them. Any relational database, including SQLite of which Room is an abstraction layer, is so called because it is designed to manage/handle multiple tables that can, but needn't, be related.

Multiple databases will result in additional code to manage the multiple databases, duplicated resources, and duplicated resource utilisation.

It is only really a sound decision to utilise multiple database if there is a requirement to do such, which would probably be restricted to security or technical issues.